# #import "msado15.dll" C++ in existing project

Tags: c++, sql-server, dll, ado, dllimport

I am a new ADO. I was trying a tutorial related to ADO. Meanwhile, I encounter this problem.

I want to import `msado15.dll` in an existing project ("MT4ManagerAPI" (if someone knows this project)). But import code shows

```
"Error: cannot open source file "C:/Users/777/Desktop/Don't Remove/Новая папка (2)/MT4-Manager-API-master/Examples/ManagerAPISample/Debug/msado15.tlh".
```

Even, I couldn't find `msado15.tlh` in an above local address.

This is my code :

```
`#import "C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\system\\ado\\msado15.dll" \ no_namespace rename("EOF", "EndOfFile")`
```

But when I import this path not existing project in newly created project everything is alright, there is no error. I wonder what is the problem? should I change something from existing project's property?

Comment: The .tlh file is generated by the import. You may need to do a clean build. If that does not work delete the Debug folder completely (make sure you have no important data files before that).

Comment: clean build? how to do?

Comment: Its an option in Visual Studio in the build menu. Look for `Clean Solution`. Again if this does not work navigate to your project folder and delete the Debug folder (again provided you have no data files there).

Comment: thank you, it fixed. but know it says "illegal escape sequence"

Comment: It will tell you the line number this occurs on.

Comment: that is in '#import "msado15.dll"' line but maybe this is caused by backslash before "no_namespace"

Comment: The backslash before no_namespace is only needed if you entered the import on 2 lines instead of 1 and the backslash is the last item on the first line. Its the same rules as the following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10419530/multi-line-preprocessor-macros