# Multiline expression: How does c compilers treat newline?

Tags: c, split, format, standards, multiline

I'm reading the introduction section of the K&R book on C. To see what code format generates errors, I tried splitting `printf("hello world!");` into different lines, as shown below. The problem is, I don't know if my results are implementation-independent. I used the GCC compiler.

What do C standards say about multiline expression? How do compilers deal with them?

```
/*
    printf("hello wor
    ld!\n");
*/

/*
    printf("hello world!
    \n");
*/

    printf("hello world!\
    n");

/*
    printf("hello world!\n
    ");
*/

    printf("hello world!\n"
    );

    printf("hello world!\n")
    ;
```

The commented-out expressions generate errors, while the remaining ones do not.

The behavior of the third expression was unexpected. Usually `"` needs to be terminated on the same line but the third expression works.

Third expression:

```
    printf("hello world!\
    n");
```

Output to console:

```
hello world!    n
```

It seems like `\` can be used to split a string into multiple lines, but the space before `n");` is included as part of the string. Is this a standard rule?

Comment: If \ is the last character on a line (no whitespace after it) then it is treated as a continuation character. It is generally used for macros. [Multi line preprocessor macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10419530/multi-line-preprocessor-macros)

Comment: Note that GCC has, for better or worse (mostly worse, IMO), relaxed rules about white space after a trailing backslash — see [Extensions: Slightly Looser Rules for Escaped Newlines](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-13.1.0/gcc/Escaped-Newlines.html).  This doesn't seem to be controllable via a command line option, though some combination of `-Werror`, `-pedantic` or `-pedantic-errors` might convert the warning into an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[C 2018 5.1.1.2](https://c0x.shape-of-code.com/5.1.1.2.html)

> 118 2. Each instance of a backslash character (\) immediately followed by a new-line character is deleted, splicing physical source lines to form logical source lines.

So basically writing

```
    printf("hello world!\
    n");
```

is identical to writing

```
    printf("hello world!    n");
```

Answer (score 2):

The compiler splits each logical line that ends with the new line character `'\n'` into tokens.

The compiler issues an error for example for this code snippet

```
printf("hello wor
ld!\n");
```

because in each logical line (that corresponds to one or more physical lines), there are incorrect tokens `"hello wor` and `ld!\n"`

You could combine these two physical lines in one logical line by placing symbol `'\'` before the new line character like

```
printf("hello wor\
ld!\n");
```

The second physical line should start in position 0 to form the string literal `"hello world!"`.

Also after splitting lines into tokens, the compiler concatenates adjacent string literal tokens. So you may write, for example

```
printf("hello " "world!\n");
```

or

```
printf("hello wor"
"ld!\n");
```

Comment: The sentence “The compiler splits each logical line … into tokens” is meaningless to a student before “token” is explained.

Answer (score 1):

Any two consecutive string literals will be combined.  Therefore, this is completely valid C:

```
printf("hello world!\n"
    ""
    ""
    "next line\n"
);
```

...or to show a single line in multi-line:

```
printf("h" "e"
    "llo " 
    "world!\n"
);
```

Comment: String concatenation is not a preprocessor function — it is done by the compiler proper after the preprocessor has finished.  See [§5.1.1.2 Translation phases](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.1.2) — string concatenation is phase 6 but the preprocessing is complete at the end of phase 4.

Comment: hehe [lanuguage-lawyer] is leaking =]

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Preprocessing directives are carried out (in phase 4) before string concatenation indeed. But pedantically, 5.1.1.2 "After preprocessing, a
preprocessing translation unit is called a _translation unit_". This happens in phase 7. String literal concatenation happens in phase 6. It is bit blurry where the "preprocessor" ends but I don't think it is correct to say that string concatenation isn't done as part of the preprocessing. What implementations like `gcc -E` may or may not spit out is another story.